# Move data from itemsource of one listbox to another listbox wp8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, listbox, rss

I am parsing a RSS Feed from one site and storing it in `listbox1` and then parsing another RSS storing it in `listbox2`. Now I want to combine the data of `listbox1` and `listbox2` in `listbox3`. It might sound silly but I am unable to do it. The main problem is I am not able to access the controls inside the listbox.

```
<ListBox x:Name="list1" ItemsSource="{Binding RSSData}" DataContext="{Binding RSSData}" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"  x:Name="txtpubDate" Foreground="#FF170505"  Text="{Binding Path=pubDate}" TextDecorations="Underline" ></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Padding="18" Foreground="#FF0E0101" x:Name="txtTitle"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Title}" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                <Image Height="200"  x:Name="imageLink"   Source="{Binding strImg}"></Image>
                <TextBlock Foreground="#FF0F0202" Padding="35" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="txtDesc" Margin="2"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Description,Converter={StaticResource RssTextTrimmer}}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This is the XAML code of my `listbox1` and I am trying to do it with `listbox3.itemsource=listbox1.itemsource;` but nothing is happening.

I also tried to add data in this way: `listbox3.items.add(listbox.items[i])`
but nothing is working.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the contents of the listbox and add them one by one for instance:

```
foreach(object item in listbox1.items)
{
   listbox3.items.add(item);
}
```

and then do the same for listbox2.

Comment: Thank you very much to answer :) but it shows an error that no AddRange is exist. listbox.Items.AddRange() this function is valid only in Windows Forms not in Windows phone 8.

Comment: Sorry about that i have updated my answer. I must have glossed over the windows phone 8 while i was reading.

Comment: Sorry to say but that isn't working, it shows an error [operation not supported on read only collection]. I guess its because when we use ItemSource the Items collection becomes read only

Comment: Does your model implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Thank you Festyk to reply, No it doesn't , Can you please give me an idea how to implement it